# Nifi :usign replace text for replacing '},' with '\n'

Tags: apache-nifi

I  have  json reponse  like this :

```
{"ID":"1","AddressType":"1"},{"ID":"2","AddressType":"1"},{"ID":"3","AddressType":"1"}]
```

and  i  want to  transform it  into   this  format:

```
{"ID":"1","AddressType":"1"}
{"ID":"2","AddressType":"1"}
{"ID":"3","AddressType":"1"}]
```

**how can  i   replcae  comman  after  {  with  new  line  in  replace text  processor?**

Comment: seems you asking how to write regular expression. what did you tried so far?

Comment: i have used this in my search value : (?s:((?<!},)\n)) and this expression ${$1:replace('},', '\n')} in replacement value but it doesn't cahnge anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

search value: `\},\{`

replacement: `}${literal('\n')}{`

---

where `${literal('\n')}` is just a new line `'\n'`

Comment: why  should  i use  unescapeXml()  with   json  response?

Comment: right it was overhead to get a new line char. modified

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `{}` characters in the search value: `\},\{` and I think `\},` as a search value can be enough.

Comment: Do  you  have  any idea  why  this isn't  valid  regular  expression

Comment: fixed search value  according to comment of @mgyongyosi.